# Text editor for iPad 2

Tags: ipad, ios, software-recommendation

I want to edit tab delimited text files with my iPad 2. I'm looking for an editor with visible spaces and line endings as well as Dropbox support.

Anybody know of such a product offering?

Comment: It is not on topic for Superuser, but a moderator should migrate your question to Ask Different shortly, where it will be on topic.

Comment: Sorry, I don't think I fully understood what you mean by visible line endings. Take a look at Code Editors for the iPad such as [Textastic](http://www.textasticapp.com/).

Comment: I'm used to windows which uses a pair of CR and LF characters to terminate lines. 
UNIX  uses an LF character only. 
Apple uses a CR character only.

I need visible tabs to signify the end of each data field and a visible line ending symbol to signify end of each record.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to take a look at Michael Tsai's *iPhone* text editor's [comparison](http://mjtsai.com/blog/2011/09/06/comparing-iphone-text-editors-v6/). It's not specifically for iPad, but summarizes (and he keeps it more or less updated). You have links to all the apps he mentions and a nice formatted table with the "features" each editor has or lacks.

He specifically added iPad support in the linked version of the entry:

```
I’ve added rows for tracking iPad
```

And of course, at the time of writing this…

> [WriteUp](http://writeup.prasannag.com/), still my preferred editor, syncs faster with Dropbox than before and now supports .taskpaper files.

<sub>*Bear in mind that Michael updates the entry every now and then. I've linked to version **six**, but for the sake of this AskExchange entry, you should check if there aren't new ones. Use a google search like [this](http://www.google.com/search?btnG=1&pws=0&q=text%20editor%20comparison%20michael%20tsai). If you don't know what google is, you can try [this other link](http://lmgtfy.com/?q=text%20editor%20comparison%20michael%20tsai). ;)*</sub>

Comment: Really? A lmgtfy link?

Comment: @LoïcWolff why not? Feel free to change it to http://www.google.com/search?btnG=1&pws=0&q=text+editor+comparison+michael+tsai

Comment: Feels a bit patronizing, that's all. I even thought they were stripped out automatically.

Comment: @LoïcWolff fixed. ;)

Answer (score 0):

i currently use [textastic](http://www.textasticapp.com/)

it supports tabs, but not sure if you can show these as symbols on the page, as i use it for writing code.

There is a pdf manual on the site which may give you the information you need.

It has dropbox and ftp/ftps support which works really well.

Comment: Here is what I have sorted out so far.Textastic displays a small gray triangle for tabs by default.

Textastic doesn't show a character for line endings, however I can see where there is a line ending by looking at the line numbers to left of each line. Wrapped lines are indented which is very helpful.

In summary Textastic can be used for occasional editing tab delimited text files.